# if $('img').attr("src", "")

Tags: jquery, if-statement, src, attr

I'm trying to use jQuery to edit the SRC of an image if it's blank. Here's my current code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            img = $('img');
        if img.attr("src", ""){
            $this.attr("src", "default.gif");
        }
    });
</script>
```

It's not working. The current error I get in my Chrome Console is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Can anyone help out? Thanks a lot in advanced.
- Jordan.

Answer (score 16):

`attr()` gets, or sets, the attribute. It doesn't assess/compare them. What you need to do is:

```
if ($this.attr('src') == '')
    $this.attr('src','default.gif');
}
```

Or, slightly faster/more efficient:

```
var that = this;
if (that.src == ''){
    that.src = 'default.gif';
}
```

And, as noted, the error message was presumably caused by the omission of the brackets around the `if` statement to be assessed.

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: +1, Also, the specific error referenced was a result of missing brackets for the `if` statement.

Comment: Why yes, that...addendum was always there! You, *uh*, must've glossed over it on your first view... [...runs...] =D

Answer (score 1):

Please give semicolon after this.

```
var $this = $(this);
```